# I can't install IceCat on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ppa, icecat

I want to install IceCat on Terminal but it doesn't work.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuzilla-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install icecat -y
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gnuzilla-team/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Comment: As you can see on the launchpad site https://launchpad.net/~gnuzilla-team/+ppa-packages "
GNUzilla Team has no related PPA packages."

Comment: Also see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnuzilla/2014-10/msg00024.html

Answer (score 5):

You can install pacage `icecat` from [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info)'s main repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/ toutatis-updates main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icecat
```

Warning: I suggested toutatis version of Trisquel because It's based on Ubuntu 12.04 (As you mentioned in question). So `sudo apt-get upgrade` aftre adding repository cause add/remove/upgrade packages in current system

---

Hence,

Alternatively you may **directly download deb** from https://packages.trisquel.info : [i386](http://packages.trisquel.info/toutatis-updates/i386/icecat/download) or [amd64](http://packages.trisquel.info/toutatis-updates/amd64/icecat/download) or choose appropriate release and package from [Main page](http://packages.trisquel.info/).

Comment: Note: I made a variation of your answer. It explains key management and a possible configuration for `apt_preferences`.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Pandya-s answer.

As mentioned, you can install `icecat` from [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info)'s main repository. This line adds the repository to your debian/ubuntu system:

```
echo "deb http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/ belenos-updates main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trisquel.list
```

Now you need to set up some trust for the repo (GPG keys). Trisquel signing keys can be seen here:
https://trisquel.info/en/wiki/download-trisquel
You should not trust me and should check the numbers on the official page, but I used this:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 0xE6C27099CA21965B734AEA31B4EFB9F38D8AEBF1
sudo gpg2 --export --armor B4EFB9F38D8AEBF1 | sudo apt-key add -
```

You have set up the repo. Theoretically, you're ready to install `icecat`. The trisquel repo is large though, you may want to limit packages that would be automatically installed. Use something like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/trisquel
    package: *
    Pin: origin "mirror.fsf.org"
    Pin-Priority: 100
```

Now you're ready to go!

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icecat
```