# How to install ice cat on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, browser, icecat

I'm considering using GNU Icecat, but it doesn't seem to be in the ubuntu repository that I can `apt-get install` from.

[Their website](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/) doesn't really come with any readmes. Is it possible to install it so that the software gets updated regularly through `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't install IceCat on ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578258/i-cant-install-icecat-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: And maybe you want to look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IceCat

Comment: @malo But does that allow me to install/remove from apt?

Comment: @warchest - I see no repository that would allow installing Icecat with apt at the present moment. But it can be run locally ('portable as they say in windowz). See my answer.

Comment: @edwinksl - In 16.04, after adding the Trisquel ppa as indicated in the linked answer: ` Package 'icecat' has no installation candidate
`.  So, not a duplicate for 16.04

Answer (score 5):

Go at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/ and download the latest package.

Extract it at your desired location.

There, you may be able to launch the browser by just double clicking the `icecat` executable, or try first, by opening a terminal in that location:

`chmod +x icecat`

To create a desktop file like for a normally installed browser:

Using `gedit` text editor:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/icecat.desktop`

Then paste this, changing accordingly the lines that start with `Exex=` and `Icon=` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Icecat Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=path/to/your/location/icecat %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=path/to/some/icecat.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;
```

Save, close, and you should see it in Dash or other launchers, or add it to a panel etc.

---

Depending on your desktop environment and/or launcher: in order to properly see the icon in the launcher, `icecat.png` file might be needed in a proper location.

Let's say we have a 128x128 file called `icecat.png` (that we can get from somewhere like [here](http://findicons.com/icon/93267/icecat?id=93267)).

Go to the location `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/icecat.png` ( or create it first), and then again `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/icecat.desktop`, change the necessary line to `Icon=icecat`.

Answer (score -1):

```
WARNING: if you use any unofficial repository and install software from
         them,you doing this on your own risk.
```

Well, you doing everything on your own risk anyway :-)
Please have a look here:
This link shows you how to search for such repos:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=icecat&show_inactive=on

then look for:
→ gnuzilla icecat for 64bit
→ https://launchpad.net/~brunoalexandremiguel/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

the last link show how to add this icecat repo like this commands do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brunoalexandremiguel/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: have you tested that? seems old and even 'no installation candidate'

Comment: Yes that repo has a very old build.